# Boot Screen problem

Tags: boot, plymouth

(sorry for my bad english)

I have a problem with the boot screen.
When i turn on my PC, i see the Ubuntu logo and after that, a black image with 5 dots (and after that i see the locker screen). The problem is: Why
i see the black screen and how to fix it ?

In this photo is what i see when PC starts:

This is what i see first:
[image]

And after, i see this:

This is what i see after:
[image]

I hope you understood me! Thanks! (I use the last Ubuntu LTS version).

My specs:
Processor: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E7500 @2.93GHz
Graphics: Geforce GT 730
OS type: 64-bit
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Are you using proprietary drivers for your GPU?

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu installed on your computer or are you trying to boot to a live media such as USB or DVD?

Comment: @L. D. James > I have Ubuntu installed on my computer.  + I added hardware specs. I use Nvidia Binary driver ver. 361.42

Comment: @Sami Press ESC on the screen and give us an image of the text behind the graphics so that we can see where it's getting hung up.

Comment: @L.D.James I pressed ESC but nothing happened.

Comment: @Sami From the `Grub menu` hit `e` and remove `quiet splash` from the second to the last line.  Then hit `F10`.  Now you should see the text and show us where it gets stuck.

Comment: @L.D.James Okay, i removed 'quiet splash' and after that appears a purple screen and after a black screen for some second and then the locker screen. No text here.

Comment: Which ubuntu version u installed... question is ,is it really  installed properly?did u make bootable stick with rufus? Try using UUI

Comment: I installed Ubuntu using a CD. I installed the latest version.

Comment: It's probably the graphics card.

Comment: @Sami  Replace the `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.  After you have done this, be sure to include @L.D.James in your updated text so that I'll receive notification to check back to this question.